# Configurable Product: Display Full Price for Options with Easylife Switcher

Tags: product, configurable-product, extensions, product-page

I am creating a website with Magento CE 1.9.1 and have installed the Easylife Switcher, which is working very well and does more or less what I want. The configurable options are set up to display as labels.

What I would like to add now are the prices for the options into the label as well.

As you may see in the attached image (first image) , the prices available under the select list for every option, however they are not included by the module when transforming the select list to labels.

Activating the configurable prices from the backend is no option however, since they only display the difference of price between the options.

My guess is that something needs to be done in the product.js for the Easylife Switcher (see second image), maybe create an "optPrice" like the "optText" that already exists - how to do that is however beyond me. this would be optimal as the Option Title and the Option Price could then be styled separately.

Would appreciate any help!

The HTML code:
[Image 1 http://allblues.eu/skin/frontend/allblues/default/images/image1.png](http://allblues.eu/skin/frontend/allblues/default/images/image1.png)

Easylife Switcher's product.js:
[Image 2 http://allblues.eu/skin/frontend/allblues/default/images/image2.png](http://allblues.eu/skin/frontend/allblues/default/images/image2.png)

Answer (score 1):

There is a config setting called `Show added configurable prices in label`. [see here what it does](https://github.com/tzyganu/Switcher/wiki/configuration).
But this doesn't do what you need. It just displays the price difference in the label or not.
So if you have a `red` color that should cost 5$ more then the label will be shown as `Red + %$`.
But you can try to manipulate the function [`getOptionText`](https://github.com/tzyganu/Switcher/blob/master/js/easylife_switcher/product.js#L155) or better yet [`handleCustomOptionText`](https://github.com/tzyganu/Switcher/blob/master/js/easylife_switcher/product.js#L201) to format the text as you need it. Right now this `handleCustomOptionText` just returns the text as it is. I added it there just for this cases. When a dev wants to change the format of the label.